# change whole layout of a custom item in a expandablelist onchildclicklistener

Tags: android

I have an expandablelist and I want to change the whole layout when you click on a child item but not a group one when. I try to select the child Items like this it changes all of the items.

```
while(parent.getChildAt(i)!=null){
    do something..
}
```

Here is the code:

```
private OnChildClickListener menuListOnChildClickListener = new OnChildClickListener() 
{
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
    {
       //change whole layout of whole children with an inflator
       //change the one clicked with another inflator
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tıklandı"+childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch(childPosition){
            case 1:
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaEkranlar.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaAnasayfa.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
            break;
            case 2:
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaEkranlar.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaAkilliEv.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaAkilliEvPerde.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaAnasayfa.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
            break;
            case 3:
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaEkranlar.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaAkilliEv.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaAkilliEvPerde.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout_sagOrtaAnasayfa.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);  
            break;  
            default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand the child items I had to count the size(size is a static variable not size() function) of my adapter first child in adapter and call it from main childOnClick while changing the layout:

```
int i=0;
while(parent.getChildAt(i)!=null){
    if((i>0 && i<ExpandListAdapter.size)){
        c=(ImageView) parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.iv_listChild);
        c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        d=(ImageView) parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.iv_listChild2);
        d.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    i++;
}
```